# insert html tags into <li> programmatically

Tags: c#, listitem

I know the solution must be simple.

I want to add list item programmatically with html tags inside the li

```
string x = "xxxx <br/> yyyy"

BulletedList.items.add(x)
```

I want to see

1. xxx
   yyy

and not

1. xxx <br/> yyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have greater flexibility over the HTML rendered on each list element, consider using a `Repeater` or a `ListView` instead. They require a little more HTML to set up your `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, but will give you arbitrary flexibility over the contents of the `<li>`.

```
<ul>
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <li>
        <div>Any HTML or data binding you want.</div>
    </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The BulletedList control will strip any html you put in it. You will have to subclass it and override it's render method to achieve this.

I use the following to associate a CssClass with the items in the list, which I can then use to pretty them up.

```
public class CustomBulletedList : BulletedList
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        base.Render(htmlWriter);
        sb = sb.Replace("&lt;div class=notes&gt;", "<div class=notes>");
        sb = sb.Replace("&lt;/div&gt;", "</div>");
        writer.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the `<br />` tag.

Comment: but i want to <br> or any other tag inside the listitem

Comment: @Maggie it's generally bad form to downvote people who didn't give you the answer you were looking for because your question was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the </BR> tag as below:

`string x = "xxxx yyyy"`

Comment: @maggie, you never mentioned in your question that you want BR tag. If this is the case than @kbrimington's solution is the right choice. You would have read your question again before down voting the answer.